# What is wrong with my bower.json file?

Tags: yeoman, bower

I recently added the following bower file to the [visualsearch](https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch) project:

```
{
  "name": "visualsearch",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "homepage": "http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/",
  "authors": [
    "Samuel Clay"
    "@samuelclay"
  ],
  "description": "A Rich Search Box for Real Data",
  "main": ["build-min/visualsearch-datauri.css", "build-min/visualsearch.css", "build-min/visualsearch.js"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jQuery": ">=1.4",
    "jquery-ui": ">=1.8",
    "backbone": "0.9.10",
    "underscore":"1.4.3"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests",
    "Rakefile",
   "vendor",
    "*.html",
    "build",
    "docs",
    "*.yml"
  ]
}
```

Visualsearch was added to the bower registry with:

bower register visualsearch https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch.git

However when I run:

bower install visualsearch --save

Visual search is downloaded into my "bower_components" directory, but backbone and underscore are not added to my projects bower file as dependencies.

Comment: Use json validators for these.. not stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a comma here between array elements:

```
"authors": [
    "Samuel Clay",
    "@samuelclay"
  ]
```

You can easily check any json at this site: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/